# Google Speech2Text - firewall blocking request

Tags: firewall, google-cloud-speech, proxies

My client has a functionality in the App where it converts an audio file into text. For this, I am using the Google Cloud Speech to text API. The client has a VM setup where there is no internet connection available, and all the network traffic should go through a proxy if it needs to connect to the internet. The SpeechToText API calls don’t go via the proxy, but directly hit the firewall, which in turns blocks it and the translation fails.

I looked for ways for using global proxies in the APP, which didn’t work as these calls are gRPC based and not REST based. Looked on gRPC code as well for the proxy settings and used one of the environment variables that they provide for the same, but even that didn’t work.
I also tried to check in the Google Speech To Text client libraries if they provide proxy related settings, but even there is no solution for that.

The Google Cloud API calls use gRPC and gRPC protocol is using HTTP/2 which doesn’t seem to provide proxy based control.

I already tried to follow the steps in the instructions, however it's still not working to send the traffic via the proxy.

Any ideas what else I can do?

https://medium.com/google-cloud/accessing-google-cloud-apis-though-a-proxy-fe46658b5f2a
https://developers.google.com/gdata/articles/proxy_setup

Comment: Not sure you'll be bale to solve this without help from the client's IT team. Verify the destination and outgoing TCP port of the traffic - you need the destination IP address( also is it IPv4, IPv6?) and which TCP port is being used. Then type all of that up and submit a ticket to the IT team.